# How to get disk name that contains a specific partition

Tags: linux, partition, disk, block-device

If I know that a partition is for example `/dev/sda1` how can I get the disk name (`/dev/sda` in this case) that contains the partition ?

- The output should be only a path to disk (like `/dev/sda`).
- It shouldn't require string manipulation, because I need it to work for different disk types.

Comment: I have a horrible solution to a getting the disk name from a file here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72219415/1569204

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can observe in `/sys` the block device for a given partition name. For example, /dev/sda1:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/block/sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root /sys/class/block/sda1 -> \
 ../../devices/pci0000:00/.../ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
```

A script to take arg `/dev/sda1` and print `/dev/sda` is:

```
part=$1
part=${part#/dev/}
disk=$(readlink /sys/class/block/$part)
disk=${disk%/*}
disk=/dev/${disk##*/}
echo $disk
```

I don't have lvm etc to try out, but there is probably some similar path.

---

There is also `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk -as /dev/sde1
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sde1    8:65   1  7.4G  0 part 
`-sde   8:64   1  7.4G  0 disk
```

and as @don_crissti said you can get the parent directly by using `-o pkname` to get just the name column, `-n` to remove the header, and `-d` to not include holder devices or slaves:

```
lsblk -ndo pkname /dev/sda1
```

Comment: No need for a script to do that, to print the _just_ the parent device run: `lsblk -no pkname /dev/sda1`

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks! I was reading help and man pages of every single unix utility that can manage partitions or list them, i cant belive that i didnt saw "PKNAME internal parent kernel device name" in lsblk.

Comment: pkname is not in my man page, but in the output of `lsblk -h`, so it's easy to miss!

Comment: meuh, it is not present in any man page version, the man page clearly says (twice): _Use_ `lsblk  --help` _to get a list of all available/supported columns_.

Comment: On my Debian Wheezy I get the error message: `lsblk: unknown column: pkname`

Comment: @Marco - yeah, debian, ubuntu and derivatives have their own version of `lsblk` (modified or something)... Most answers related to `lsblk` columns usually get this kind of comment from people who use those distros.

Answer (score 1):

It's work only with UTF-8 locale. lvm, zfs, raid tested ok.

```
parent_tree_disk() {
  lsblk | awk '/^[A-Za-z]/{d0=$1; print d0};/^[└─├─]/{d1=$1; print d0, d1};/^  [└─├─]/{d2=$1; print d0, d1, d2}' | sed 's/[├─└─]//g'
}

alias pd='parent_tree_disk'
```

*shell command:#* pd
NAME
sda
sda sda1
sda sda2
sda sda2 cl-root
sda sda2 cl-swap

*shell command:#* pd | awk '/sda2/{print $1}'
sda

And you can use other filter on pd list output, like sort, uniq...

Comment: seems to miss some of the items
`$ lsblk -no NAME
sda
├─sda1
├─sda2
├─sda3
│ └─luks-20ed40f5-be3e-4b02-9373-3c2f8c620ffe
├─sda4
│ └─luks-5fe2e868-ee82-4f02-8611-52368db5df86
├─sda5
│ └─luks-d4a78f37-2228-49e0-a841-612c4ba70a78
├─sda6
│ └─luks-8e91e1ae-21f3-42de-b317-cff1da21a015
├─sda7
│ └─luks-85259675-1f76-4cbf-9a3e-e96c3c3bd39d
├─sda8
│ └─luks-51f5e5c3-439f-4169-85f8-26a50836068b
└─sda9
  └─luks-7bbcf4e3-2f11-4a4a-84d9-26f9a97c9c2a
sdb
└─luks-b4abb505-4480-4b43-a4fc-ea376d8737da
sdc
└─sdc1
sdd
├─sdd1
└─sdd2`
Then your output only does 3 items for sda9

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not beautiful:

```
for d in `fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | grep "^Disk " | cut -d":" -f1 | cut -f2`
do
  if [ `fdisk -l $d 2>/dev/null | grep -c "/dev/sda1"` -gt 0 ]
  then
    echo On disk $d
  fi
done
```

It works only for 'real' disks not for LVM.