# How can I get parent, children, siblings of a block device in Linux?

Tags: linux, dependencies, block-device

I need an algorithm, that can determine the possible *children*, *parents* and *siblings* for any given **block device** (virtual or physical). In the past I have solved that problem for *multipath devices* and *LVM Logical Volumes*, but I'd like to have a complete algorithm.

For example a multipath device is given. That device could have four paths (disks), and the device could be partitioned. One partition could be part of an MD-RAID, the RAID could be partitioned, too, and one such partition could be used as LVM Physical Volume (PV) to build a Volume Group (VG) with several Logical Volumes (LV).

Comment: so, in short - what `lsblk` does?

Comment: @frostschutz: Did you try? In my case when staring at an LV (`/dev/sys/home`), I get the PV only, but not the parent of the PV (for example). And it outputs `cr_home`, which in turn cannot be used as parameter for further inspection (`/dev/cr_home` does not exist; it's a device-mapper device (`dm-8`)). So in short: Why did you think this would be the solution?

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226420/how-to-get-disk-name-that-contains-a-specific-partition) get you most of the way there?

Comment: @U.Windl it resolves PV parent fine for me (disk->partition->raid->luks->lvm) and that's usually considered good enough™. It stops at loop devices though. There are other kinds of virtual block devices (like NBD), those could be anything really (up to userspace to decide), no sane way to cover everything

Comment: @number9: I did read that question before asking my own. `lsblk -as` helps a bit, but it skips virtual devices (`cr_home` for example).

Comment: @frostschutz: Older versions of `lsblk` lack option `-s`, and that version cannot handle multipath devices properly.